# OWASP ModSecurity Docker image access forbidden for page behind Cloudfare

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, http-status-code-403, mod-security

I'm using the latest docker image in reverse proxy mode
I keep receiving the same message 403 forbidden, I think cause the ModSecurity image try to reach the site directly with its ip and without Host header
How can I resolve?

Comment: What do you get in Nginx's error log?

Answer (score 5):

Your issue is likely with the `Host` header that is being set by NGiNX. If you connect to `localhost`, the transmitted `Host` header will be `localhost` and the receiving server will most likely not accept that.

If this is indeed your issue, then you can diagnose it by setting the `Host` header explicitly, and see whether that solves it. For example:

```sh
curl -H "Host: real.host.name.com" localhost:8080
```

Note that the container behaves as designed. However, a case could be made to support a case where all requests to the proxy use the `Host` header that matches the proxy target. If you feel that you need that, please open an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/coreruleset/modsecurity-docker/issues/new. We'll be happy to help.

Comment: Hi, your solution works like a charm, however I've done some test, I think it's better to set the PROXY_PRESERVE_HOST default value to off(it's less confusing), in that mode the Apache version works with no problem,the Nginx one ignore the value of PROXY_PRESERVE_HOST probably cause the proxy_backend.conf file that sets the Host header

Comment: Glad I could help. Well, "confusing" really depends on your use case. If you deploy the container as the frontend to your application then it's the expected behaviour. `PROXY_PRESERVE_HOST` is specific to Apache httpd. There currently isn't an equivalent for NGiNX (we always use the incoming `Host` header), but, as I wrote above, we'd certainly be open to discussing it.